# The enclosure on a grid

Tags: mathematics, geometry

On an infinite 1 by 1 grid, we want to make an enclosure with 20 fences that are each 5 units long. The two ends of each fence has to be on a node of the grid. What is the maximal area of the enclosure? (Fences can cross nodes and the enclosure has to be a polygon.)

[image]

Comment: Are curved fences allowed in this context?

Comment: No, they are not.

Comment: Great puzzle. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The largest area is 769.

> $4\times 192+1 = 769$
>  [image]

I think the mistake that other people are making is that they are making mirror-symmetric solutions. Instead, it is best to make a rotationally symmetric one.

Comment: Congratulations! You found the trick :p

Comment: That’s actually super interesting how by simply switching a couple of the slanted lines directions you get an extra 1 area. Does anyone know if there is any mathematical reasoning behind that? Well done on finding the answer by the way! :)

Comment: I feel so dumb for not getting that extra 1, from my drawing it’s obvious that you can combine 4 of those shapes in such a way that there’s 1 square “for free” in the middle.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil the mathematical reasoning is that the resulting shape is rounder, basically.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I've changed the picture to show where the extra 1 comes from.

Comment: BTW, I did write a computer program to check all possibilities to make sure that this really is the maximal area.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Changed my vote to +1.

Answer (score 8):

**Largest area: 768**

The largest (I've found) is as follows:

[image]

I believe this will be the maximum, if not very close to it, as the theoretical maximum area is only $789.22$ (see further down for why).

### Here are some other attempts:

Starting simply, the area of a square with side length of $25$ is $625$:

[image]

Next is my favourite, a snowman. Sadly he has quite a small area, but I'll add him here anyway. This shows that adding lots of small polygons doesn't work.

[image]

And a diamond is big , at $736$:

[image]

And I initially overlooked an even larger one at $741$:

[image]

But the largest will be when the shape is as circular as possible (see further down for why), which is this shape at $768$:

[image]

I'm using [this website](http://print-graph-paper.com/virtual-graph-paper) to draw these, which very helpfully tells you the length of the line you are drawing.

---

**Little bit of maths, that got me thinking how to solve this:**

From a node, there's only a few other nodes that can be connected such that the length is $5$ units. Using Pythagoras's theorem we can see only a couple of these 'possibilities' have a length of $5$:

[image]

So from one node (in the first quadrant), these are the possible lines that can be drawn:

[image]

Now the maximum area of a n-sided shape will be a regular polygon with n sides ([Nice proof here from Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868026/given-a-polygon-of-n-sides-why-does-the-regular-one-i-e-all-sides-equal-encl)). So for $n=20$, the greatest area will be when those 20 sides form an [icosagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosagon).

**The greatest possible area, therefore, if we didn't have to connect to nodes would be $789.22$**

The internal angle of an icosagon is $(180 \times (n-2)) / n = 3240/20 = 162$ degrees. So the maximum area will be when these fences are set so they have an angle of $162$ degrees between each one. However this wont be possible.

Going back to the possibilities, and using some trigonometry, the angles are:

[image]

As you can see, it won't add up to $162$, no matter how you place them. There are also no n-sided shapes with internal angles of $126.87$ or $143.13$ either.

So to get the biggest area, the largest possible n-sided polygon needs to be formed. **This means the largest area will be when the shape is as round as possible.**

This is the basis which I am using/used to find large areas.

Comment: Why not use all the angles available and construct a 12-gon? You've only done octagons so far.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis the bottom polygon of the snowman is a 12-gon. I have one other possible idea for a 12-gon that might work, I'm still somewhat experimenting. This is very difficult to prove :)

Comment: The largest I made is 753, but it’s still not the answer.

Comment: @Displaymaths how do you know? I'd be surprised if theres anything more

Comment: I got 768, will add soon :)

Comment: @DrunkWolf I just found it, sorry :P

Comment: @Displaymaths is 768 the answer?

Comment: Nice, I just posted my 757 which I thought was pretty optimal

Comment: @BennettBernardoni it looks like a similar shape to the 768, so not surprising it also has a large area :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil no need to apologise, you added it before i posted mine so there was no cheating involved ;) it's all good

Comment: @DrunkWolf well done on finding it though! That was a tricky one to create (although now I think about it, all the maths I did at the bottom of my answer was pretty much telling my to make a shape round as possible, which for some reason I was ignoring to make snowmen :P )

Comment: The answer is 769.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Your answer is one less.

Comment: @Displaymaths interesting. I'll see if I can find it!

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Well in general, a circle has the best "circumference to area"-ratio of any shape possible, so to make the optimal shape all we need to do is maximize the circumference and this ratio, circumference is maxed at 100, which we can maintain by simply using length 5 pieces, and the ratio we optimize by making the shape as circular as possible :) It was the first shape i tried for these reasons.

Answer (score 7):

Basically, we make a shape as round as possible, with as long pieces as possible. So only pieces with length 5, in a symmetrical arrangement. If we mirror this around the x and y axis, we use 20 pieces, and have surface 768. [image]

Answer (score 6):

Best I've done is 757 which looks like this:

[image]

$\text{Area}=15*15+4*15*7+4*(4*4+3*4)=757$

My process was to start with a 5 fence by 5 fence square and then push out the middle bits by using 3x4 diagonals to make the polygon more circle shaped. If you push out the middle bits another time you get 753 which is close, but slightly worse.

Comment: You are pretty close to the answer